# Extract each "name" and "Type declarations" from XSD Schema - nested definations using the python

Tags: python, xsd, lxml, elementtree

I have several schema definition files that I need to capture to a CSV or tabular format file, I'm trying to extract the names and types; the types declaration is complex type and it's in another file as described as follows:
The goal is to print in a tabular format from the following example using Python:

```
Name        type1       type2       declaration
Name_1      def_192     codeType1   integer
```

Is there a Python module, that can extract the type definition from the nested definitions?

main_call.xsd:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="main_type.xsd"/>
---
--
<xs:element name="name_1" type="tns:def_192"/>
<xs:element name="name_8" type="tns:def_2398"/>
```

main_type.xsd:

```
 <xs:complexType name="def_192">
    <xs:group ref="tns:codeType1"/>
  </xs:complexType>

 <xs:group name="codeType1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="value" type="integer" length="8"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
```